# Accessing object's properties from another class

Tags: php, oop

I'm playing around with OOP in PHP and I've got the following code:

**index.php:**

```
<?php
include('user.class.php');
include('page.class.php');

$user = new User;
$page = new Page;

$page->print_username();
?>
```

**user.class.php:**

```
<?php
class User {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->username = "Anna";
    }
}
?>
```

**page.class.php:**

```
<?php
class Page extends User {

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function print_username() {

        echo $user->username;
    }
}
?>
```

My problem occurs in the class "Page", in the print_username() function.

How do I access the $user object's properties within this class? I am, as you can see, defining the two objects in index.php.

Thanks in advance

/C

Comment: Pass `$user` as parameter

Comment: if one class is going to extend the other, there is no point initiating each class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class User {
    public $username = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->username = "Anna";
    }
}

class Page extends User {
    public function __construct() {
        // if you define a function present in the parent also (even __construct())
        // forward call to the parent (unless you have a VALID reason not to)
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function print_username() {
        // use $this to access self and parent properties
        // only parent's public and protected ones are accessible
        echo $this->username;
    }
}

$page = new Page;
$page->print_username();
```

**`$user` should be `$this`.**

Comment: shouldnt he do a parent::__construct(); inside the Page's constructor?

Comment: @Neal **He's learning.* He should know how to forward calls if he implements the methods unless he has a reason not to do so.

Comment: @steven And what am I doing?

Comment: @CodeAngry yes, i voted you up. I thought it wasn't done in your primary post. Maybe you did it later by an edit or i didn't read correctly...

Comment: @steven I feel slightly offended... but I'll get over it. That mistake is for amateurs :) `I != amateur`

Comment: @CodeAngry `I != Angry`

Comment: This isn't a very good design, IMO.  Pages inheriting from Users?  I respect fiddling around with something like this for learning, but I wouldn't do this in production code.

Comment: @J.Polfer I'm only fooling around, I know it doesn't make sense for a sharp system. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
class User {
    public $username = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->username = "Anna";
    }
}

class Page extends User {
    public function print_username() {
        echo $this->username;  //get my name! ($this === me)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see some confusion here:

1. You've caused your `Page` class to inherit from `User`.  This means that the page *itself* has all the properties of the `User` class, and in fact, could be used in place of a `User` class.  As the print_username() method is written in your code, it won't work - because it doesn't have a reference to a `$user` variable.  You could change `$user` to `$this` to get a username in the `print_username()` method, and borrow from the parent class (`User`) to get the username property.
2. My thinking is though, that you didn't intend to do that.  A Page is not a User, after all - they aren't related to each other.  So what I'd do instead is remove `extends User` from the Page class.  This will make a Page a Page, and a User a User.
3. But how is the Page going to print a username?  Pages need to do that of course.  What you could do instead is pass the $user object as a parameter to the `Page`'s `__construct()` method, and then you can reference that value in your `Page`.

The first way of writing the code, using extends, involves *inheritance*.  The second way of writing the code when passing in the user as a parameter involves *composition*.  In a situation like this, with two separate ideas (Pages and Users), I would use composition to share and access object properties instead of inheritance.

I would do this instead:

```
<?php
class User {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->username = "Anna";
    }
}

class Page {

    private $user;

    public function __construct($user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function print_username() {

        echo $user->username;
    }
}
$user = new User;
$page = new Page($user);

$page->print_username();

?>
```